# Erro ao mover diretório

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um `folderBrowserDialog` que quando selecionamos a pasta ele moveria-a para um determinado diretório.

Eu estou a ter o seguinte erro:

> Impossível criar um ficheiro quando esse ficheiro já existe.

mas a pasta não existe.

O código é o seguinte

```
    private void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string domain2 = Domain + folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(Domain))
            {
                Directory.Move(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, domain2);
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Domain + "\\projects");

            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

**Update**

esqueçime de dizer o seguinte Domain é a seguine string

```
string Domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "projects";
```

eu fiz esta pequena alteração.

```
    private void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string domain2 = Domain + folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(Domain))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.Move(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, domain2);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Faild to move the file maybe it already exist");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Domain + "\\projects");

            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

continua com o mesmo problema

Comment: Já tive problema semelhante com uma aplicação em outra linguagem (acredito que seja um problema do Windows, se for a mesma situação). Verifica por favor se esta pasta não foi criada com outro usuário e não está visível apenas para o usuário atual, o que impediria que uma nova fosse criada com mesmo nome, mas ao mesmo tempo via código identifica como se a pasta não existisse. Eu sei - é bizarro.

Comment: Essa diferença de pastas entre usuários que notei acontece por rodar a aplicação em modo Administrador e criar uma pasta que o usuário não administrador não consegue visualizar.

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi o problema.
Eu estava a tentar mover a pasta para 

`Domain + folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;`

ou seja o que eu estava a tentar fazer era isto 

C:\Localização do ficheiro move para C:\DirectorioC:\A localização do ficheiro outra vez.

Este é o código

```
    private void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string domain2 = Domain + "\\Edit";
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(Domain))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.Move(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, domain2);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Faild to move the file maybe it already exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Domain);
                try
                {
                    Directory.Move(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, domain2);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Faild to move the file maybe it already exist", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```